# Ascending chain condition for 1-element normal closures in a free group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, free-groups

> Let $F$ be a free group of finite rank. Does $F$ satisfy the ascending chain condition on normal subgroups each of which is a normal closure of one element?
>
> In other words, can there exist elements $r_1,r_2,\dots\in F$ such that
> $\langle r_i^F \rangle \subsetneqq \langle r_{i+1}^F \rangle$, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

I'm sure the answer should be known, but I have not yet been able to find a reference for it.

Let me add some background.

- B.H. Neumann [An essay on free products of groups with amalgamations. Philos. Trans. Roy. Soc. London Ser. A 246 (1954), 503–554.] proved that in the free group of rank $3$, $F_3$, there is an infinite strictly ascending sequence of normal subgroups $N_1 \subsetneqq N_2 \subsetneqq \dots$, such that each $N_i$ is the normal closure of **two** elements in $F_3$. Moreover, there is an automorphism $\alpha \in Aut(F_3)$ such that $N_{i+1}=\alpha(N_i)$, $i \in \mathbb N$.
- A.M. Brunner [On a class of one-relator groups. Canadian J. Math. 32 (1980), no. 2, 414–420.] constructed a sequence of (pairwise non-isomorphic and Hopfian) one-relator groups $G_0,G_1,\dots$, such that for all $i<j$, $G_j$ is a proper quotient of $G_{i}$ by the normal closure of a single element. (Unfortunately this does not answer my question since the group $G_0$ is not free.)

Comment: In other words, does there exist a "locally 1-relator infinitely presented f.g. group"?

Comment: @YCor, I'm not sure "locally $1$-relator" is the right terminology. For any non-Hopfian $1$-relator group $G$ we get a sequence of non-injective group epimorphisms $F \to G_1 \to G_2 \to \dots$, where each $G_i \cong G$, and the limit is an infinitely presented group. But I think that the kernel of the resulting map $F \to G_i$ cannot be the normal closure of a single element, for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I just coined it! Why should this example make the terminology clumsy? I'd say a group $F/N$ is locally 1-relator if every finite subset of $N$ is contained in the normal $F$-closure of some element of $N$. Your example is a directed limit of 1-relator groups, which is not one thing usually referred to by "locally".

Comment: @YCor "Locally" has an established usage meaning finitely generated subgroups have a given property, so "Locally 1-relator" would be read as f.g. subgroups are 1-relator.

Comment: OK I agree, then rather "1-locally-related"? (Note: locally 1-relator agrees with the established usage of 'locally' in that $N$ is locally 1-generated as $F$-group. But indeed it makes the whole thing confusing. Certainly anyway, I want to qualify the group rather than the presentation.)

Comment: I agree with Autumn on this... Perhaps we should say that the presentation is "locally $1$-relator"?..

Comment: If your question has a positive answer, then there exists in $F$ elements $x$ such that $\langle\!\langle x\rangle\!\rangle$ is maximal among 1-generated normal subgroups. Does this exist? I don't immediately see whether a primitive element satisfies this, and more generally whether one can characterize such elements.

Comment: @YCor: a primitive element $x$ indeed gives rise to a maximal normal closure. If $y \in F$ is an element s.t. $M=\langle \langle x \rangle\rangle$ is strictly contained in $N=\langle \langle y \rangle\rangle$, then $F/M$, the free group of rank $d-1$, where $d=rank(F)$, surjects with non-trivial kernel onto the $1$-rel. group $F/N$. It follows that $y$ is itself a primitive element in $F$ (b/c the $1$-relator group has rank strictly less than $d$), hence $F/N$ is also free of rank $d-1$, contradicting the Hopf property for free groups.

Comment: @YCor: see also Proposition 5.15 in Chapter II of Lyndon-Schupp's book.

Comment: Thanks! for record, this proposition (5.15 in Chapter II of Lyndon-Schupp, attributed to Magnus, 1931) says that in a free group the normal closure $\langle\!\langle x\rangle\!\rangle$ of a primitive element $x$ is a maximal 1-normally-generated normal subgroup, and if it equals $\langle\!\langle y\rangle\!\rangle$ for some $y$ (not assumed primitive) then $y=x^{\pm 1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104060/discussion-between-ashot-minasyan-and-ycor).

Comment: @Ashot: note that there are chains of arbitrary finite length:  $[x,y,    ,y] , ..., x$,  I have never seen an infinite chain..

Comment: @Ashot: do you know any pair or cyclically reduced words $u,v$ such that $|u|>|v|$ and $\ll v\gg \subsetneq \ll u\gg$?

Comment: @MarkSapir There's an example here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300431/can-a-hyperbolic-one-ended-one-relator-group-have-a-shorter-trivial-word/300541#300541

Comment: @MarkSapir My intuition that there's no such infinite chain is that the sequence of quotients should be eventually faithful.  Like if the sequence of one relator groups is eventually hyperbolic this would be true.

Comment: @AutumnKent: Thank you!

Comment: It's obvious to have an infinite decreasing chain, namely $(\langle\!\langle x^n\rangle\!\rangle)_{n\ge 1}$ for some primitive element $x$. So infinite chains are very usual, but the issue is to find increasing ones.

Comment: @Mark and Autumn: here is an even easier example: the relation $[x,y]=1$, of length $4$, follows from the relation $xy^n=1$, of length $n+1$. So arbitrarily long relators can have consequences of length $4$...